# How do I call another Perl CGI script within a CGI script?

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a Perl CGI script that creates a login screen, i.e. user name and password.

I want, after successful login, the user to be redirected to the next action within the application (another Perl CGI script).

What is the command to redirect one CGI script or to an HTML page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example using [CGI](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html) as [David Dorward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789555/how-do-i-call-another-perl-cgi-script-within-a-cgi-script/1789577#1789577) mentions.

```
use CGI;

if (redirect_needed) {
    # If redirect is desired, don't print headers...
    print CGI->redirect("http://some.other.url/");
    exit; 
}

# If no redirect is desired...
print CGI->header();
# etc...
```

Comment: But if you call anything like CGI->header() before the redirect, the redirect method does not work.

Comment: @gath: Correct.  Actions like sending redirects, setting cookies, and setting the `content-type` of your output are all actions that must occur in the HTTP headers, which in turn must be the first output from your script to STDOUT.

Answer (score 5):

In HTTP terms you should have your program output a [302 or 303 status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) and a [Location header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

If you are using [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/CGI.pm-3.48/lib/CGI.pm) then you can use [the redirect method](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/CGI.pm-3.48/lib/CGI.pm#GENERATING_A_REDIRECTION_HEADER) to achieve this.